# How to assign a string with full file path along with filename from an entry in WalkDir

Tags: file, rust

I want to recursively traverse through a directory. Hence I'm using this below code.

```
for entry in WalkDir::new("D:\\Code").into_iter().filter_map(|e| e.ok()) {
        println!("{}", entry.path().display());
    }
```

This works and prints file name along with full path in output(command line).

But I want to get the **full file name along with its path to a string**. So that, later I wan't to read the file content and do few other things.
This I'm not able to do it.

I tried this

```
let f_name = String::from(entry.file_name().to_string_lossy());
```

But this gets only file name without path.

Comment: just concat path and name

Comment: @Stargateur: since it is recursive, if I concat path and name, I'll miss the inner directory info. Also I'm new to rust, may be I'm missing something simple also

Comment: with `let d_name = String::from(entry.path().to_string_lossy());` I got the directory name. Thanks @Stargateur for the hint.

Comment: Why do you want the path as `String` and not as `PathBuf`? For using the file, the latter is strictly more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With below code, I got the full file path along with file name.

```
let d_name = String::from(entry.path().to_string_lossy());
println!("{}", d_name);
```

**Output:**

```
D:\Code\sub_folder\filename.cpp
```